# Any command, i.e 'ipconfig' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables

I added Python to the environmental variables path, because I wanted to run it from outside its directory:

[image]

But now I face a greater issue that no command is being recognized. Especially Powershell commands which is related to my job.

Even simple ipconfig or any command isn't recognized.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not "add" to your path, but overwrote it completely.

Path on Windows should at least contain `"C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem"`, and `"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\"` for Powershell (powershell.exe), - so you need to change the Path variable into

```
"C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\ul340\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39"
```

Btw, you should consider to add such user dependent path components only for the specific user. This can be done inside the same dialog (see screenshot) in the upper part.

Comment: I'd set default folders *before* Python one, just to be sure...

Comment: Yes, I tend to sort PATH by expected frequency of usage - but for practical use it doesn't matter. Furthermore, I would add this user dependent path to the user specific parts in the upper part of the dialog. Add a note about this.

Comment: My powershell app it's not working (`C:\Users\ul340\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell`)
Should I also add path `C:\Users\ul340`
Since there's lots of programs installed there that I'll use? So it will be: `"C:\Users\ul340\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Users\ul340"`?

Comment: No - seems for Powershell you need to append "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\"

Comment: Got it, thanks it works now! But everytime I want to run a new program located in `C:\Users\ul340`, I will now have to append it in the environmental variables?

Comment: You may collect those programs in, say, `c:\users\ul340\bin` and add that to the PATH. Also you could simply use the location of the program like `.\test.ps1` or `$env:USERPROFILE\bin\test.ps1`.